# Regularly check whether a webserver is up with a Thread

Tags: python, exception, urllib, python-multithreading

I wrote a Threading class which tests whether a webserver is up or not.

```
import urllib
import threading
import time
import Queue

class Thread_CheckDeviceState(threading.Thread):


    def __init__(self, device_ip, queue, inter=0.1):

        self._run = True
        self._codes = {}
        self._queue = queue
        self._device_ip = device_ip
        self._inter = inter
        self._elapsed = 0

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)


    def stop(self):
        self._run = False


    def run(self):
        start = time.time()

        while self._run:
            try:
                code = urllib.urlopen(self._device_ip).getcode()
            except Exception:
                code = "nope"
            finally:
                measure = time.time()
                self._elapsed += measure-start

                print self._elapsed, code
                self._codes.update(
                    {self._elapsed:code}
                )

            time.sleep(self._inter)
        self._queue.put(self._codes)

q = Queue.Queue()
thread = Thread_CheckDeviceState("http://192.168.1.3", q)
thread.start()
time.sleep(10)
thread.stop()

print q.get()
```

It works fine - until I disconnect my pc from the network. From that moment on the thread just does nothing until it is stopped. I would expect it to just continue and set the `code` to `"nope"`, like I wrote it in the exception handler. Why doesn't it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `urllib2` instead, and specify a `timeout` parameter when you call [urlopen()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen).